# How to make the same scale of x and y in gnuplot without full autoscaling?

Tags: gnuplot, scaling

I know that "set view equal xy" automatically sets the same scales for x and y, but it is not exactly what I want. I expect that I define 'xrange [a:b]' and 'yrange [c:?]' and the last number '?' would be defined automatically from the knowledge of 'set view equal xy' and from the knowledge of the lengths of the axes.

I can try to explain in other words. I write the following:

```
reset
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-1:?]
set view equal xy
plot sin(x) with lines
```

The resulting scaling depends on the plotted function and gnuplot does not follow the entered values. But it should be possible to calculate '?' just from the knowledge of the visible lengths of axes (Lx,Ly) and condition of 'equal scales' (Sx=Sy):

```
Sx = Sy
Lx/(-5-5) = Ly/(-1-?)
? = - Ly/Lx * (-5-5) -1
```

This is what I expect from gnuplot when asking for equal scales. Could anyone help me to achieve this 'not fully auto'-scaling? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure what you want, but using `set yrange [-1:*]` should work fine. That autoscales only the upper y-value:

```
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-1:*]
set size ratio -1
plot 2*x, 0.2*x
```

The output with 4.6.5 is:

[image]